# Check location settings changes at runtime

Tags: java, android, google-maps, geolocation

I'm using a basic location updates behavior to get user location, as explained in [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html).

It works pretty well, but I'm stuck with something that seemed to be simple:

**How can I know if the user disable his location while the app is running?**

I can check if location is enabled using [Settings Client](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsClient) when starting my activity, but how to do so at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a broadcast for that: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#MODE_CHANGED_ACTION

code is something like:

```
private final IntentFilter filter =
          new IntentFilter(LocationManager.MODE_CHANGED_ACTION);

private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
   @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       if(LocationManager.MODE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction()) {
            // check here the new location status
       }
   }
};

// then to register
context.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
/// and unregister
context.unregisterReceiver(receiver);
```

Comment: Perfect! I just had to register this BroadcastReceiver when requesting location updates, and unregister it when my activity terminates. Thanks!